# Key error 'image'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

While trying to POST store, Store, Product, StoreCategory, Merchant data are saved to database, however I still get an error of

> KeyError at /api/stores/create/ 'image'

The error is at `image = store_categories_data["product"].pop("image")` but on the terminal while debugging, image instance returns `image pop results OrderedDict([('image', <InMemoryUploadedFile: grocery.jpg (image/jpeg)>)])`

Why I am getting this error?

```
    store_categories_data 
    OrderedDict([('product', OrderedDict([('image', OrderedDict([('image', <InMemoryUploadedFile: bag.jpg (image/jpeg)>)])), 
    ('name_of_product', 'Ladies Pink Bag'), ('description', 'description'), ('price', Decimal('1600')), ('active', True)])), 
    ('store_category', 'BAGS')])
    '''
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class StoreCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    store_categories = StoreCategorySerializer()
    merchant = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields=("id",
                "merchant",
                "store_categories",
                "name_of_legal_entity",
                "pan_number",
                "registered_office_address",
                "name_of_store",
                "store_contact_number",
                "store_long",
                "store_lat",
                "store_start_time",
                "store_end_time",
                "store_off_day",
                )
    def create(self,validated_data):
        store_categories_data = validated_data.pop('store_categories')
        merchant_data = validated_data.pop('merchant')
        for merchantKey, merchantVal in merchant_data.items():
            try:
                merchant,created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=merchantVal)
                print('merchant',merchant)
                validated_data['merchant']=merchant
                store = Store.objects.create(**validated_data)
                image = store_categories_data["product"].pop("image")
                print('image pop results',image)
                '''
                image pop results OrderedDict([('image', <InMemoryUploadedFile: grocery.jpg (image/jpeg)>)])
                '''
                image_instance = ProductImage(**image)
                print('image_instance',image_instance)
                image_instance.save()
                product = store_categories_data["product"]
                product_instance = Product(
                                            store=store,
                                            image=image_instance,
                                            name_of_product=product['name_of_product'],
                                            description=product['description'],
                                            price=product['price'],
                                            active=product['active']
                                        )
                product_instance.save()
                store_category = store_categories_data['store_category']
                store_category = StoreCategory(product=product_instance, store_category=store_category)
                store_category.product.store = store
                store_category.save()
                return store
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise NotFound('not found')
```

**Models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name_of_legal_entity = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    name_of_store = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store_off_day = MultiSelectField(choices=DAY, max_length=7, default='Sat')
    store_categories = models.ManyToManyField('StoreCategory',blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    image = models.ForeignKey('ProductImage',blank=True,null=True)
    name_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')

    @property
    def imageName(self):
        return str(os.path.basename(self.image.name))


class StoreCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="store_category")
    store_category = models.CharField(choices=STORE_CATEGORIES, default='GROCERY', max_length=10)
```

Comment: Are you making certain that an image is submitted in your request?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule sorry i did not get you.

Comment: You can try and use ```store_categories_data.get("product").pop("image")```. I think your serialized validated data is being lazy loaded.

Comment: I had tried that and i got the same error.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're popping the "image" key?

Comment: To pass image to ProductImage model. You can see Product Class in models.py where image is a foreignkey

Comment: You can index directly without popping. ```image = store_categories_data["product"]["image"]```

Comment: now i get AssertionError: `create()` did not return an object instance error.

Comment: return store throws an error